# How can I add Selected attribute with the the drop down list item

Tags: html, asp.net-core, cascadingdropdown

I have the following Record, and from the record I am trying to create the cascade dropdown. It is working fine but how can I add the selected attribute if the data item has selected = true. I have the following record. How can I add conditionally selected attribute
if item.IsSelected , Selected = IsSelected.

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return new List<Category>
        {
            new Category { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName="Category 1" },
            new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName="Category 2" },
            new Category { CategoryId = 3, CategoryName="Category 3" }
        };
    }
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> GetSubCategories(int categoryId)
    {
        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory> {
            new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 1, CategoryId = 1, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 1", IsSelected=false},
            new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 2, CategoryId = 2, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 2" IsSelected= false },
            new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 3, CategoryId = 3, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 3" IsSelected= true},
            new SubCategory { SubCategoryId = 4, CategoryId = 1, SubCategoryName="SubCategory 4" IsSelected= false},
             
        };
        return subCategories.Where(s => s.CategoryId == categoryId);
    }
```

```js
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CategoryId").on("change", function() {
            var categoryId = $(this).val();
            $("#SubCategoryId").empty();
            $("#SubCategoryId").append("<option value=''>Select SubCategory</option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=SubCategories&categoryId=${categoryId}`, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#SubCategoryId").append(`<option value="${item.subCategoryId}">${item.subCategoryName}</option>`);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add conditionally selected attribute if item.IsSelected ,
> Selected = IsSelected.

Just try this code:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
         $("#SubCategoryId").append(`<option value="${item.subCategoryId}" 
            ${item.isSelected ? "Selected" : ""}>${item.subCategoryName}</option>`);
     });
```

Here is the test result:

[image]